# Nox player sound not working?

Tags: audio, noxplayer

I just installed Nox Player with Android 4.4.2 and at first, its sound was working. I played some games, but after some hours as I closed it and restarted it, since then at starting the sound first played, and then in 2 to 3 mins it goes off. To listen to the sound again, I have to restart the player, and then again in 2 to 3 mins, it does the same.

Any solutions?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't joined the site after the question was migrated, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to properties of nox.exe and then compatibility mode and Uncheck "Run this program in compatibility mode for windows 8" and Check "Run this program as an Administrator"

this work for me hope work for you also